# Force Quality for YouTube (or other) Video

Tags: php, html, video, youtube

Being new to streaming videos:

1. I don't know how to properly ask the question
2. I don't know of the proper place to ask the question
3. I'll use YouTube as the base example

Let's say I render a video in high quality and I want to play it on my website with the embedded YouTube player (or jw).  The video is hosted from my server, not YouTube.

Is there a way to force one set of users to see low quality vid and one set of users to have the option of seeing it in high quality (b/c of connection speeds they may not want hq)?  I'm hoping to run a forum and the quality of the video would be a benefit to contributors or registered members.

I'd like to know how to do this server-side.  I know the YouTube player has a quality param, but I'd like to be able to force the quality.  If a scripting language is needed, I'm using Perl, but I'm open to a PHP alternative.

One other question that ties into this: if you have a video in hq, is it possible to play that in low quality, or would I have to render different versions of the same vid?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are hosting it yourself, the youtube player seems to be out of question, doesn't it?

To achieve what you are planning, the player plugin you are using has to support multiple qualities. Now, when generating the player embedding code in php, check if the current visitor is a user, if yes, supply the player with all video qualities, if not, just with the lowest one.

To display different qualities, you'd have to seperately render the videos.

Comment: Thank you! It's kind of difficult to find info on the topic. `if you are hosting it yourself, the youtube player seems to be out of question, doesn't it?` I'm not sure, does it? I thought there'd be a way, especially since Google is so open about their APIs and they have an embedded option. `check if the current visitor is a user, if yes, supply the player with all video qualities` For some reason that sounds like adding a wrapper.  From what I read that's not advised because wrappers don't cache as well due to the added params?  Does that sound right to you - granted this may be the only way?

Comment: `To display different qualities, you'd have to seperately render the videos.` So you can't upload in 1080p and have it scale down to 320p dynamically?

Comment: The youtube player (embedded or not) grabs the video from the youtube page. It's not really adding a wrapper, it just generates the embedded player differently. yes, you could dynamically rescale it, but that would ineffective. You could upload the 1080p vid and scale it down on the server though.